# How can I improve this actions in API controller?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, asp.net-web-api, code-readability

### Overview

I am designing one api that will be integration with another system, however I stumbled upon one code which I know it can be improved but I don't know how to do it properly.

### Code

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Reserve")]
    public IHttpActionResult Reserve([FromUri]ReserveData reserveData, [FromBody]BetsData bet)
    {
        var result = new ReserveResponse();
        // Question 1.
        if (reserveData == null || !IsDataForReserveValid(reserveData))
        {
            // Question 2.
            return Ok(_responseStringBuilder.BuildWrongRequestResponse().Create());
        }
        // Question 3.
        if (!_customerService.CheckIfCustomerExists(reserveData.cust_id))
        {
            return Ok(_responseStringBuilder.BuildCustomerNotFoundResponse().Create());
        }
        if (_customerService.IsCustomerRestricted(reserveData.cust_id))
        {
            return Ok(_responseStringBuilder.BuildRestrictedCustomerResponse().Create());
        }
        if (!_reserveService.ReserveAmount(reserveData.cust_id, reserveData.amount))
        {
            return Ok(_responseStringBuilder.BuildInsufficientFundsResponse().Create());
        }

        if (bet != null)
        {

        }

        _reserveService.InsertReserve(reserveData);
        return Ok(_responseStringBuilder.BuildNoErrorsResponse().Create());
    }
```

### Requirements

This is simple action that should return Ok with string in its response content.

### Questions

1. Is there any better what of checking for valid input? I've created
   hierarchy of methods validating input of each action in this
   controller(because most of the input for different actions is actually repeating) as
   private methods in the controller.
2. I've created string builder pattern and I build each time my request with needed properties. Is this the best way?
3. There is some business logic which I've put in the controller, but I am not sure if it should be in the service layer or not Should I leave it like that or invoke single method from a service which does all the logic by itself there and simply returns result to me if there are errors or not?

   ```
   Example response would be:
   ...(some data)
   error_code=NoErrors\r\n
   error_message=There were no errors\r\n
   ```

Comment: Why always 200 Ok? There are 404 NotFound, 400 BadRequest etc

Comment: This was the requirement :(

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy
I'd argue that 200 for each API response is actually not a bad thing. Take a look at Facebook API as an example. That's not something OP should worry about.

Comment: @kuskmen What do you mean by your second point? Are you using StringBuilder to construct JSON, XML or other data format your API returns? Why won't you leverage Web API automatic formatting and instead return an object inside Ok()? Something like return Ok(Response.NoErrorResponse), for instance. NoErrorResponse could contain properties you want, like ErrorDescription, ErrorCode, etc.

Comment: I don't see any usage of result = new ReserveResponse(); What is it for?

Comment: @VladStryapko First of all, thanks for helping. Code is not yet complete , yet I have a feeling that I am doing it wrong hence I asked the question here. Regarding your questions above, the thing is that the service consuming the responses from this API expects string as response and this was the requirement.

Comment: Using two attributes `[FromUri]` and `[FromBody]` together seems to me violations RestApi principles. Try using one of two.

Comment: @adamshakhabov Why? It is always like that. Custom types are bind from the body and build-in types are  bind from the uri , these attributes are only making this explicit which imo is better. See this for reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 2):

Here are my 2 cents:

> Is there any better what of checking for valid input?

If possible, put the validation attributes on your models for basic validation. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) as an example.

For more business-oriented validation, I think it should happen inside a method which encapsulates an action, so your checks against customer restriction and other stuff would go there. The method could throw an exception with a meaningful message if something is wrong and then you could catch the exception, take its message and construct a response using it.

> I've created string builder pattern and I build each time my request with needed properties. Is this the best way?

As you've stated you need a string as a response. Is there any particular format, though? If yes, I'd advise to leverage [custom formatters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-formatters) to put the formatting logic in one place.

> Should I leave it like that or invoke single method from a service which does all the logic by itself there and simply returns result to me if there are errors or not?

Typical service layer should care about business validation and business logic. That is, format of the request and primitive validation can be put outside of this method but the method itself should validate passed parameters anyway and can't rely on caller providing them correctly. However, I should note that such questions are extremely opinionated and depend on particular use case. There are a lot of possible approaches and there isn't reason for a controller to be a proxy just as there is no reason for a controller to be bloated.

Also, this should probably go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Started doing refactoring by the things you suggested in order to evaluate the differences of the approaches , however this turned into another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965841/inheritance-and-model-validation-using-validation-attributes

Comment: _The method could throw an exception with a meaningful message if something is wrong and then you could catch the exception, take its message and construct a response using it_ Should use `try-catch`? If yes, then where: controller action or service method?

Comment: @adamshakhabov
My suggestion is the following - use try catch explicitly only if you do something specific. Otherwise you may use filters or middleware to catch each exception and present its Message. So, neither in controller nor in service. Some people prefer to wrap every error in Service layer in something like 'CouldNotCreateUserException' but I think it's debatable and not necessarily needed.