# Inheritance and model validation using validation attributes

Tags: c#, .net, validation, asp.net-web-api, model

### Overview

It seems that model validators aren't working the way I think they should, let's consider following example:

### Code

```
/// <summary>
///     Model that holds reserve data passed to <see cref="ReserveController"/> Commit and Cancel actions.
/// </summary>
public class BaseReserveData
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Customer identifier in operator's database.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int cust_id { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    ///     Reserve identifier in operator's database.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public long reserve_id { get; set; }
}
/// <summary>
///  Model that holds base reserve data plus amount and request identifier that are passed
///  to <see cref="ReserveController"/> Reserve and Debit actions.
/// </summary>
public class TransactionalReserveData : BaseReserveData
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     The amount to be reserved.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public decimal amount { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    ///     Request identifier.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public long req_id { get; set; }
}
```

### Questions

I am testing with this request -

```
host/api/Reserve/Reserve?cust_id=0&reserve_id=1&amount=1.01&req_id=2
```

But when I check in action if my model state is valid it returns true, despite the range validator attribute in the base class of this model. Am I missing something?

### Notes

Action signature, model is only used for passing to service and data layers.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Reserve")]
public IHttpActionResult Reserve([FromUri]TransactionalReserveData trxReserveData, [FromBody]BetsData bet)
```

### Updates

1. I am checking for validation by simply invoking `ModelState.IsValid` in the Reserve action method.

Comment: from where you're sending the post request?

Comment: External services does that

Comment: Can you specify any source from where you're passing these values? I believe these validations are View Based, So you have to tell the view that you need to validate a specific field. Have you tried passing 0 in all the fields?

Comment: This model is created from uri query parameters of Reserve action, which is used for passing data to service and data layers, so there is no front-end(and it is not used for view logic), applogies for the small info I will update my question with action signature when I sit on my computer.

Comment: @AmitMishra updated my question.

Comment: How exactly do you check if the model is valid?

Comment: Are you totally sure it returns false? Did you observe that via debugging? I've reproduced your classes and method on my local Web API project and everything's working perfectly.

Comment: It actually returns true , but it should return false imo, check Range attribute at cust_id , and check the request I am testing with